# Resizing Images Node js-Imagemagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick module with node js in order to do some modification on images (resizing) the problem with this code is keep getting this error

```
Error: Command failed: Paramtre non valide - /butterfly.jpg
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\xxxx\Image-manipulation-using-NodeJS-and-imagemagick-master\node_modules\imagemagick\imagemagick.js:88:15)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5) {
 timedOut: false,
 killed: false,
 code: 4,
  signal: null
 }
```

the code that I'm using

```
const im = require('imagemagick'),
      srcImage = "C:\xxx\xxxx\Image-manipulation-using-NodeJS-and-imagemagick-master\source_images/butterfly.jpg",
      desPath = "C:\xxx\xxxx\Image-manipulation-using-NodeJS-and-imagemagick-master\destination_images/";
app.get('/image/resize', function(req, res) {
    var optionsObj = {
        srcPath: srcImage,
        dstPath: desPath+"butterfly_lowquality.jpg",
        quality: 0.6,
        width: ""
    };
    im.resize(optionsObj, function(err, stdout){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({
            "message": "Resized Image successfully"
        });
    });
});
```

Any idea or better solution for resizing images using node  ?
Best Regards

Comment: any idea please or available project that I can follow

Comment: You are not getting a valid image, most likely because the path is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

I use sharp to compress images as it has lesser dependencies which are good for the production environment. Also, it uses method calling than sending a JSON object which gives you control over which operation happens first. Here is a gist of the code I'm using.

https://gist.github.com/ArunJRK/33cbd1952c9b70186145f19eae65d73f

Below is a sample full code is available in the gist

```
var sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs');
const paths = require('path');

const pipeline = await sharp(path).rotate().resize({width: 1500});
 
        pipeline
        .webp()
        .toFile(`${compressed}.webp`, 
            function (err) { //note the directory needs to exist else will throw err
            if (err) console.log(err,`Illegal file : ${name}${ext}`)
});
```